# how do I create a nameless async function - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if it's possible to create a nameless function with the quick functional notation on javascript. What I mean by changing this:

```
var lobby = ((io) => {

...
}
return {
  getWhiteBoardId: (name2, time2, role2, pass2, need_id) => {
                  let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    setTimeout(() => res("Now it's done!"), 1000)
                  });

            // wait until the promise returns us a value
            let result = await promise; 
            }
  })(io);
```

I then want to later be able to call this function:

```
whiteboardId = lobby.getWhiteBoardId(req.body.name, req.body.time, req.body.role, req.body.pass, need_id);
```

to have something at the beginning such as this:

```
var lobby = (async (io) => {
```

so that I can call my Promise and await

Comment: Is there a problem with `var asyncfn = async io=>{}`?

Comment: Yes, when I try that I get an error

Comment: @rickster26ter1 _What error_?

Comment: I'm almost positive the problem is that `getWhiteBoardId:` should be `getWhiteBoardId : async (name2...)`

Comment: I tried both ways. The way with the latter I get:   async getWhiteBoardId: (name2, time2, role2, pass2, need_id) => {"...    SyntaxError: Unexpected token : referring to after getWhiteBoardId    When trying the former I get:     
            let result = await promise;
                         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: that syntax is wrong.  async has to be before the function declaration

Comment: Ahh, I see. Ok, yes that way works with no compile errors. Thanks! I did notice that the output of whiteboardId = lobby.getWhiteBoardId(req.body.name, req.body.time, req.body.role, req.body.pass, need_id); is now wrong. Anything I need to do different there?

Comment: also in your code the async and then await promise is redundant.  you can just return the promise.  unless you are doing something with result before returning it (which you probably also need to do)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know if setTimeout performed asynchronously, that was my purpose in creating this function. Since that's the only way I could see to get await (Async timeout)

Comment: Note: JavaScript is single-threaded.  It does not run async in multiple threads.  eg: `setTimeout(()=>{while(1)},0);setTimeout(()=>console.log('wat'),100);` will still lock up the thread and wat will never execute

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention I am running this on nodejs...I know, that was a mistake. Just wanted to get more answers, since it's similar to nodejs in a lot of ways. With this one particular, I didn't want to lock up my server, and thus wanted async.

Comment: you will need to break the task into chunks and defer the task chunks in the event loop (eg: with Promise or setTimeout), so other tasks can execute between chunks (by being ahead in the event loop), and/or use workers, or use a threading library

Comment: Ok, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// defining io, to execute the code, you not need to write the next line
const io = {};

const lobby = ((io) => {
  // some pre-existing code
  return {
    // you are using await in this method so add async to the method signature
    getWhiteBoardId: async (...args) => {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(args), 1000)
      });

      // wait until the promise returns us a value
      let result = await promise;

      // ... some other code/logic as needed

      // i have assumed you need to return the result
      return result;
    }
  }
})(io);

// TEST: calling getWhiteBoardID method
lobby.getWhiteBoardId("Hi", "There").then(console.log);

// or

(async () => {
  const res = await lobby.getWhiteBoardId("Hello World")
  console.log(res);
})();

console.log("First!");
```